# SUM with join 3 tables

Tags: sql, join, sum

I have these tables:

Hraci:
    IDHrace (int)
    Jmeno (varchar)

Ucast_Zapas:
    ID_Hrace_zapas (int)
    branky (int)

Zapas:
    ID_zapas (int)
    kategorie_zapas (int)

Kategorie:
    IDkategorie (int)

My code:

```
SELECT Jmeno, COUNT(Ucast)
FROM Hraci
INNER JOIN Ucast_Zapas ON Ucast_Zapas.ID_Hrace_zapas=Hraci.IDHrace
INNER JOIN Zapas ON Zapas.ID_zapas=Ucast_Zapas.ID_Hrace_zapas
INNER JOIN Kategorie ON Kategorie.IDkategorie=Zapas.Kategorie_zapas
WHERE (Ucast=1)AND (Kategorie_zapas=1)
GROUP BY Jmeno;
```

but it isn´t work :/

Comment: What happens? Is there an error or just no data returned?

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: do you get data if you comment out the WHERE clause?

Comment: What error do you get? Which table has the `Ucast` column?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Please explain. Also try to post some sample data and the desired output.

Comment: Ucast column is from table Ucast_Zapas....I want to write Kategorie_zapas(kategory of player) number and want to see Jmeno (player name)...

Comment: If I comment out the WHERE clause, i have all match, where player played.

Comment: god your column names are so complicated :) what happens if you do count(Ucast_Zapas.Ucast)

Comment: Now my code is:

    SELECT Jmeno, COUNT(Ucast)
    FROM Hraci
    INNER JOIN Ucast_Zapas ON Ucast_Zapas.ID_Hrace_zapas=Hraci.IDHrace
    INNER JOIN Zapas ON Zapas.ID_zapas=Ucast_Zapas.ID_zapasu_ucast
    INNER JOIN Kategorie ON Kategorie.IDkategorie=Zapas.Kategorie_zapas
    WHERE (Ucast=1)AND (ID_zapasu_ucast=10)AND (Zapas.Kategorie_zapas=2)
    GROUP BY Jmeno;

but sql give me all players, which played in ID_zapasu_ucast=10 (ID of match),but (Zapas.Kategorie_zapas=2) not run...

Comment: the result of select count(Ucast_Zapas.Ucast)from Ucast_Zapas is number 4

Comment: i would recomend to put up sqlfiddle. Its very easy for us to understand then and provide nice solution. Hope you know sqlfiddle.

Comment: Sample: postimg.org/image/jhbwoujdv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your `WHERE` clause is wrong:

```
WHERE Hraci.IDHrace = 1
```

Comment: Now my code is:SELECT Jmeno, COUNT(Ucast)
FROM Hraci
INNER JOIN Ucast_Zapas ON Ucast_Zapas.ID_Hrace_zapas=Hraci.IDHrace
INNER JOIN Zapas ON Zapas.ID_zapas=Ucast_Zapas.ID_zapasu_ucast
INNER JOIN Kategorie ON Kategorie.IDkategorie=Zapas.Kategorie_zapas
WHERE (Ucast=1)AND (ID_zapasu_ucast=10)AND (Zapas.Kategorie_zapas=2)
GROUP BY Jmeno;